# How to create a summary table using 2 variables in R

Tags: r

How can you create a summary table for 2 variables, one being a categorical variable and another as quantitative variable.

For example my data looks like this:

| sex | Income |
| --- | --- |
| M | $24000 |
| F | $23000 |

I'm wanting a table like the summary() function.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(sum(Income))`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
df$sex <- factor(df$sex)
df$Income <- as.numeric(sub('$', '', df$Income, fixed = TRUE))
summary(df)
```